# How to create 2 diff. localisation for 2 target in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, localization

In my iOS Application, I have 2 targets for both targets I am having localisation of same language but have diff. localisation string.

for one target I have created localisation like below which is working fine
[image]

But for 2nd target, I can't have the same "Localisable.string" so I am having "Localisable-ABCD.string"
[image]

but for 2nd target, my localisation is not working.

Is there any way to localise for 2 targets?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to set a target for different localization files.

**Step 1:**
First, create a group folder for both targets with the same name and different locations. Like this

[image]

**Step 2:**
Set target membership for both files from the file inspector pannel.

For Target 1 Localizable.strings file

[image]

For Target 2 Localizable.strings file

[image]

Note : Target 1 is the main app target in your project

Comment: Perfect answer. Thank You